# Javascript push keeps deleting first item

Tags: javascript, date

I have very strange problem. I am creating an array of date objects (mondays)

```
// array to hold week commencing dates
        var mondays = [];
        mondays.push(today);
        var novi = new Date(today);

        while(novi < endDate){

            var next_monday = new Date(novi.setDate(novi.getDate() + 7));

            day_index = next_monday.getDay();
            if(day_index == 1){
                mondays.push(next_monday);
            }
            // increment the date
            novi = next_monday;
        }
        console.log(mondays);
```

UPDATE: Thanks for reply. I created new object at start and used that one.So again i am creating empty array, then adding one date to it before starting loop, then first item in loop doesnt get added, even tho it gets pushed. What am i doing wrong?

This is console.log that i am getting from above.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/04bckfcrwl7yvwd/Screenshot%202016-09-28%2018.29.25.png?dl=0

Comment: If *today* is a Monday, then adding 7 days will always land on a Monday and the *day_index* test is not required. ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ```
> today.setDate(today.getDate() + 7)
> ```

You are modifying the date object you pushed into the array.

The first item isn't being deleted, it is being changed.

> ```
> var next_monday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 7));
> ```

Then you create a new date object from it.

---

Create the new date object **first**, then modify **that**.

Comment: Thanks!
I added new object before loop, but now its skipping second date.

I added: 

var novi = new Date(today);

then used variable "novi" instead of today for whole loop. So i get first date, then second skipped somehow, then rest are fine. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v21ylipmlkgsfhf/Screenshot%202016-09-28%2017.59.51.png?dl=0

Comment: @GoranJakovljevic — You appear to still have the same problem. The only difference is that you are creating the first date object before the loop but inside the function instead of passing it into the function.

Comment: Thanks, i created new date object for it and it works.